# fortran code-algorithm for qr decomposition of non-square matrix

Tags: matrix

I am trying to implement QR factorization of a non-square matrix in FORTRAN.  I have the algorithm for a square matrix but not for a non-square. I use Housholder matrices. Do you know where I could find the whole algorithm or code for the non-square case so that I can be sure I am doing it the right way (i am new in programming!)? I have to solve (backsubstitute) for the upper trangular R and the orthogonal Q at the last part but the decomposition must be done for the non-square case. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Trefethen and Bau's book [Numerical Linear Algebra](http://books.google.com/books?isbn=0898719577) has the Householder QR algorithm in chapter 10, and it's written considering general rectangular matrices. It's also in [Matrix Computations](http://books.google.com/books?isbn=1421407949) by Golub and van Loan. Both books give algorithms more or less in the form of Matlab code, so you'll have to do some translation between the two.

You can find a Fortran implementation of QR in [LAPACK](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/double/), as well as numerous other algorithms.

Comment: Just to emphasize this answer, the QR routines in lapack do handle nonsquare inputs out of the box. The relevant routines for e.g. double numbers are dgeqrf (for factoring A=QR) and dormqr (for applying Q*C to some other matrix C). You should be able to backsolve by R using dtrsm in the "tall-skinny case", I'd have to consult the documentation myself for what to do about the trapezoidal R that arises in the "short-fat" case.

Answer (score 0):

MINPACK uses a non-square QR factorization with pivoting, i.e. it's not a real QR decomposition (like the one in LAPACK), but a generalized more robust QRP decomposition (where P is the permutation matrix representing the pivoting).

Answer (score 0):

I have these subroutines the one does the qr factorization for the nxm matrix A and it stores the upper triangular R and the w of the householder matrices in A while it saves the diagonals of R in d vector.then i try to form the Q^Tb so that i can solve the Rx=Q^tb with backsubstitution.I use it to do a data fitting with least square method(so with the backsubstitution i am supposed to take the coefficients) but it gives me  wrong results. If you have any ideas of what i am doing wrong it would be of great help because I cannot see where  the problem is!Thank you for your help!

subroutine qrdecomposition(a,c,d)
implicit none

real, dimension(n,m) :: a
  real, dimension(m) :: c
real, dimension(m) :: d
      logical :: sing
      !integer :: i,j,k,n,m
      real :: scale1,sigma,sum1,tau
      sing=.false.
      do k=1,m
    scale1=0
        do  i=k,n
          scale1=max(scale1,abs(a(i,k)))
      end do
        if(scale1.eq.0.)then
          sing=.true.
          c(k)=0.
          d(k)=0.
        else
          do  i=k,n
            a(i,k)=a(i,k)/scale1
        end do
          sum1=0.
          do  i=k,n
            sum1=sum1+a(i,k)*a(i,k)
       end do
          sigma=sign(sqrt(sum1),a(k,k))
          a(k,k)=a(k,k)+sigma
          c(k)=sigma*a(k,k)
          d(k)=-scale1*sigma
          do  j=k+1,m
            sum1=0.
            do i=k,n
              sum1=sum1+a(i,k)*a(i,j)
          end do
            tau=sum1/c(k)
            do  i=k,n
              a(i,j)=a(i,j)-tau*a(i,k)
          end do
       end do
        end if
    end do
      d(m)=a(m,m)
      if(d(m).eq.0.)sing=.true.
      return
      end subroutine qrdecomposition

```
 subroutine qrsolution(a,c,d,b)
  implicit none
  !integer :: n,m
 real, dimension(n,m) :: a 
  real, dimension(n) :: b
  real, dimension(m) :: c
  real, dimension(m) :: d

  !integer :: i,j
  real :: sum1,tau
  do  j=1,m-1
    sum1=0.
   do  i=j,n
      sum1=sum1+a(i,j)*b(i)
```

end do
        tau=sum1/c(j)
        do  i=j,m
         b(i)=b(i)-tau*a(i,j)
      end do
   end do

do  i=m,1,-1
        sum1=0.
        do  j=i+1,m
        sum1=sum1+a(i,j)*b(j)
      end do
       b(i)=(b(i)-sum1)/d(i)
    end do
      return

end subroutine qrsolution